# using terraform/terragrunt to create multiple redshift clusters sharing same subnet group and security group

Tags: amazon-redshift, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I'm attempting to create a set of terraform/terragrunt scripts to create a number of Redshift clusters.  I'd like them all to share the same subnet group and security group, and for those to be created if they don't already exist.  My initial attempt was to create a module "redshift" defined like:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "default" {
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.default.id}"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "default" {
  name        = "${var.redshift_security_group_name}"
  vpc_id      = "${data.aws_vpc.default.id}"
}

resource "aws_redshift_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "${var.redshift_subnet_group_name}"
  subnet_ids = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids}"]
}

module "redshift" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/redshift/aws"
  version = "1.4.0"

  cluster_identifier           = "${var.cluster_identifier}"
  cluster_database_name        = "${var.cluster_database_name}"
  cluster_node_type            = "${var.cluster_node_type}"
  cluster_master_password      = "${var.cluster_master_password}"
  cluster_master_username      = "${var.cluster_master_username}"
  vpc_security_group_ids       = ["${aws_security_group.default.id}"]
  preferred_maintenance_window = "${var.preferred_maintenance_window}"
  publicly_accessible          = "${var.publicly_accessible}"
  redshift_subnet_group_name   = "${var.redshift_subnet_group_name}"
  parameter_group_name         = "${var.parameter_group_name}"
  cluster_number_of_nodes      = "${var.cluster_number_of_nodes}"
  cluster_iam_roles            = ["${var.cluster_iam_roles}"]
  tags                         = ["${var.tags}"]
}
```

This works for creating a single cluster, when creating a second clusuter terraform fails to recognize that the security group and subnet group already exist.  What's the proper way to handle this?  Break the network setup out into its own module, and have the redshift module depend on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a one-to-many relation between your subnet group and your clusters then you should split the networking components in a separate module than the redshift one.

Comment: That's becoming apparent.  I was under the mistaken assumption that the behavior of a resource block was "create if not exists".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle resources at AWS is to group them by their lifecycle and/or purpose.  I would never want a database created in the same stack as application servers or resources as those can change over the life of an application, but the database might not.

If your case,  you are correct that TF will create the resources if they don't exist, but you misunderstood the context.  TF will create them if they don't exist in the state file, not at AWS.  If two stacks try to create the same resource with the same names, stack 1 will create them, stack 2 will try but fail because the resource already exists at AWS.

I would separate the security groups and subnet groups into their own module, then use a data source to reference them in the Redshift module.